# Adding id to TextView results error

Tags: java, android

Im new in developing apps for android. Ive got this piece of code (which is working fine) (it is part of layout/main.xml):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

and this code (which is not working well):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

WTF, guys? If i run the second code I will receive "Sorry! The application x has stopped unexpectedly[...]" If I remove this text view at all it is also working well (i don't interact whit this TextView in my code. What is wrong whit this?

Please help,
Chris

EDIT:

This is my only method (it is only beginning of the project ;) )

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.days, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

and here is the rest of main.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Wybierz dzień:"
    />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/day_prompt"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: more code please. maybe you have somwhere a findViewById(R.id.text) whith a different cast and aleready a object with the same id but a different type

Comment: If I had to guess, it has to do with using the keyword "text" as an id.

Comment: Can you post your LogCat error here?

Comment: 04-07 16:39:05.856: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393): ERROR: thread attach failed

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01"
          android:id="@+id/TextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Then it has something to do with something else, can you post the adb locat output?

Comment: 04-07 16:39:05.856: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393): ERROR: thread attach failed